# Alternative to giftedchat react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

In all the react-native tutorials I have seen so far, on building a chat app, I see them using gifted chat.

After installing the library, it is really buggy and slow. Below are some things I experience when using it.

1. When I have messages over 100, it takes time to load my chats.
2. When I press the send button, It takes time as well before updating the chat list(about a second).

Are there any other alternatives to gifted chat?

Answer (score 0):

Slowness or fastness would depend on the "backend" (database and/or server) you are integrating your chat app (or component) with. Firebase (from Google) FireStore or Firebase Realtime DB would be one of the best options to choose from. [This](https://medium.com/@phylypo/react-native-simple-chat-with-firebase-and-giftedchat-f7dbdff2883a) might help you in integrating Firebase DB with gifted-chat.

Comment: Even with only one message, pressing send on gifted chat is slow. Before I even started fetching from the server

Comment: Most likely some issue in your implementation or slowness in the testing environment/app. You should update your question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

react-native-gifted-chat seem not to be actively maintained.

I found [react-chat-elements](https://github.com/detaysoft/react-chat-elements#readme) I did not try it yet.

If you found something else please leave a comment.

good look with your search.